# Откуда взялось ё в словоформах «гнёзда», «вёдра» и др.?

Tags: фонетика, историческая-грамматика

Переход звука [э] в ['о] происходил с XIII по XIV вв., когда ять (ѣ) еще не дал [э] в русском.

Откуда тогда в словах *гнёзда (гнѣзда), вёдра (вѣдра), звёзды (звѣзды), сёдла (сѣдла), приобрёл (пріобрѣлъ), цвел (цвѣлъ)* взялся ['о]?

Answer (score 1):

Почему с 13 века? Как регулярное фонетическое явление переход Е в О начал отмечаться в памятниках XII в., но способ передачи нового гласного выработался не сразу: в древнерусских памятниках письменности использовались О, ЕО, ЬО (у ФОДОРА – грамота на бересте XII в.; ЕЛЕОНА – Новгородское Евангелие XIV в.; ДНЬОТЪ – Новгородское Евангелие XIII в. и др.). С XVII в. на его месте появились сочетания букв ИО, iО, а со времени Н.М.Карамзина – Ё (1794 г.). Правда, в последнее время авторство оспаривается в пользу Е. Дашковой.

Можно предположить, что изменение Е в О проходило в 2 этапа. 
1.После исконно смягченных согласных и йота оно происходило раньше и проявилось на юго-западной территории, отразившись на украинском языке (чоловiк, йому). В остальных случаях в украинском языке произошло отвердение предшествующего согласного: СЭСТРЫ.

2.В результате развития у согласных вторичного смягчения оно возникло в областях, которые вошли в русскую и белорусскую народности. Таким образом, в русском и белорусском языках переход Е в О происходит после любого мягкого согласного.

В.Н. Сидоров связывает этот процесс с утратой редуцированных, когда твердый согласный оказался в одном слоге с предшествующим гласным. Твёрдый согласный, обладая определённой степенью лабиализованности, попадал в один слог с предшествующим гласным и лабиализировал его. Участие губ при произношении твёрдого согл. привели к переходу Е в О, сохранив при этом мягкость предшествующего согласного. Так появляется мягкий согласный перед гласным непереднего ряда, что сыграло большую роль в перестройке фонетической системы русского языка: развивается вторичное смягчение согласных, возникает корреляция по твёрдости/мягкости, и происходит перераспределение функций между гласными и согласными в слове.

Изменение Е происходило и на конце слов, но оно, как предполагают исследователи, вызвано аналогией: КОПЬЁ, МОЁ, ЖИТЬЁ, ПЛЕЧО, БЕЛЬЁ, ЛИЦО по аналогии с СЕЛО, БЕЛО.

Переход Е в О как особый фонетический процесс ограничивается периодом с XII по XV в. В дальнейшем он теряет силу фонетического закона. Об этом свидетельствует сохранение Е перед Ц, отвердевшим к XV веку: ОТЕЦ, МОЛОДЕЦ, КОНЕЦ.

В настоящее время изменение Е в О утратило фонетический характер и используется как морфологическое средство при образовании: множественного числа имён существительных – СЕЛО-СЁЛА; прошедшего времени глагола мужского рода – НЕСУ - НЁС, ВЕЗУ - ВЁЗ, ПЕКУ - ПЁК; в окончаниях глаголов настоящего времени – НЕСЁМ, НЕСЁТ;

в уменьшительно-ласкательных суффиксах: ЛУГ - ЛУЖОК, СУК - СУЧОК, БОК - БОЧОК и т.д. Морфологический характер чередования обусловливает переход Е в О по аналогии: в окончаниях глаголов - НЕСЁТ-НЕСЁТЕ, в уменьшительно-ласкательных суффиксах в новых словах, заимствованных после XV в.: ФЛАГ - ФЛАЖОК, ДНЕВНИК - ДНЕВНИЧОК, ЯКОРЬ - ЯКОРЁК; в связи с выравниванием основы: ЗЕЛЁНЫЙ - ЗЕЛЁНЕНЬКИЙ, БЕРЁЗА - БЕРЁЗЕ и др.

Мало того, в этих словах вообще О не должно быть . **В О переходит Е только из Е (исконного) и Ь. Нет перехода Е в О на месте старого Ђ (ятя)**, так как во время действия этой закономерности Ђ обозначал ещё особый звук: СЕНО, ЛЕТО, БЕЛЫЙ, СЕРЫЙ, ВЕРА, ДЕВА и т.д. **Исключение** составляют некоторые слова, где **переход Е в О обусловлен аналогией при образовании множественного числа:** ЗВЕЗДА - ЗВЁЗДЫ, ВЕДРО - ВЁДРА, ГНЕЗДО - ГНЁЗДА по аналогии с ЖЕНА - ЖЁНЫ, СЕЛО - СЁЛА; ПРИОБРЕСТИ - ПРИОБРЁЛ по аналогии с ВЕСТИ - ВЁЛ.

Подробнее: https://studopedia.su/14_128418_perehod-e-v-o.html

Answer (score 0):

Постановка вопроса о каких-то ограниченных сроках действия закона "перехода" E в Ё совершенно безосновательная. Закон этот имеет место и сейчас. Например, в заимствованных словах ("шофёр"  - "шоферюга") и даже там, где его в принципе не может быть (ошибочные "?афёра", "?гренадёр").

Большинство слов с Ё на месте исторического Ять появились в период, когда различия в произношении Е и Ять уже практически сошли на нет, поэтому ничего удивительного, что многие слова с историческим Ять уподобились тем, где был истинный Есть. 
Правда, по поводу некоторых случаев (один из них как раз "звёзды") Грот писал, что это исключения, где Ё появилось на месте Ять без всякого видимого повода. С другой стороны, правописание Е и Ять само по себе не всегда держалось на исторической закономерности, ряд слов приобрели Ять по Воле самого Грота. 
(В Вики всё есть.)

Таким образом закон, если его формулировать просто как "Ять в Ё не переходит" - в лучшем случае статистическая закономерность, не имеющая императивный силы.

Comment: Вы спутали две вещи: **закон**, действовавший в древнерусском, и **тенденцию**, наблюдающуюся в современном русском. О *шофёре* писал А. А. Зализняк, кажется, даже есть хорошая задачка. Вопрос совсем не о правописании, так что «Бледного беса» вспоминать не будем. К сожалению, вы ничего не написали о причинах случившегося — то, что «без всякого видимого повода», и так, простите, видно.